# Line drawing using DDA

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew, dda

I need to draw a line using DDA with user input of x1, x2, y1, y2, but when I run the code and input Xs and Ys only empty window shows up.
What is wrong and how can I make it draw a line?

It's my first time using Glew and Glfw, so I am not familiar with it. Will be thankful if you explain me what I should change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

class line{
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    void drawline(){
        int dx, dy, step, x, y;
        float xinc, yinc;
        dx = x2 - x1;
        dy = y2 - y1;
        if (abs(dx) > abs(dy))
            step = abs(dx);
        else step = abs(dy);
        xinc = dx/step;
        yinc = dy/step;
        x = x1;
        y = y1;
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
        glVertex2d(x, y);
        for(int i = 0; i < step; i++){
            x += xinc;
            y += yinc;
            glVertex2d(floor(x), floor(y));
        }
        glEnd();
        glFlush();
    }
public:
    line(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
        this -> x1 = x1;
        this -> x2 = x2;
        this -> y1 = y1;
        this -> y2 = y2;
    }
    line(){
        
    }
    void draw(){
        this -> drawline();
    }
};

void drawtheline(int x1, int x2, int y1, int y2){
    line a;
    a = line(x1, x2, y1, y2);
    a.draw();
}

void init(){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glClearColor(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluOrtho2D(0 , 640 , 0 , 480);
}


int main() {
    int x1, x2, y1, y2;
    std::cout << "Enter x1 and y1: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x1 >> y1;
    std:: cout << "Enter x2 and y2: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> x2 >> y2;
    GLFWwindow *window;
    if (!glfwInit()){
        return -1;
    }
    window = glfwCreateWindow(720, 480, "DDA Line Drawing", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window){
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){
        glfwPollEvents();
        init();
        drawtheline(x1, x2, y1, y2);
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first problem is the use of deprecated immediate mode (glBegin/glEnd).

Comment: Should I remove it? What should I use instead?

Comment: You should use buffers and shaders instead. It is considerably more time consuming, but certainly worth the effort.